# Design Patterns: add x to y, where should the method go?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class X and class Y which is basically a collection of Xs. I want to write a method to add an X to a specific collection Y. this method will change some state on X and of course on Y. My question is where is it best to have this method, in X class (so the method will be x.addToY(y)) or should it go on the Y class (y.addX(x))? what are the considerations I should make?

Comment: if `y` is a collection of `x` then you would add an `x` in-to a `y` so the add method would go in `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is very simple, but imagine that `Y` can hold other elements different of `X`, say elements of types `A`, `B` and `C`. Are these types supposed to know how to be added to a collection `Y`? The answer is no, but if so, you would have to implement a `AddToY` method for each of these types, which is not good at all. The collection `Y` is the one who knows how to add items to itself, regardless of what types are those items. This is known as [*Separation of Concerns*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and it mainly states that every type or entity should have the functionalities that are of its concern. In this case, you can see that a collection should be able to add items to itself, but a certain type `X` may have nothing to do with a collection, thus, it shouldn't have the functionality of adding itself to a certain collection. Hope this help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if you put the method in X to add itself to Y while Y contains a collection of X, then X would have to know about Y and Y would have to know about X; whereas if you put the method in Y then Y would need to know X, but X would not need to know about Y.  You avoid circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the common sense association of such a method with the Y class, another consideration is concurrency:  while this may at first be a single threaded app, you (or someone else) may extend class Y in the future to enable synchronized multithreaded collection access, in that case, it would certainly be more convenient to have `addX` in Y so that the multithreaded subclass can override that method with its concurrency support.